# How to simulate keystrokes in C#

Tags: c#

How can I simulate keystrokes so that in other applications this simulation is read as keystrokes in C#?

I've tried using `SendKeys.Send("{i}");` but it doesn't help (the application is running in the background).
If you open the chat in the game while executing the program, then the symbol that I entered in `SendKeys.Send` will be displayed in the chat, but if the chat is not opened, then the inventory that is programmed for the "i" button will not open.

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces are used to denote special keys like `{Up}` or `{Esc}`. Specify the normal characters directly.

```cs
SendKeys.Send("i");
```

See: [SendKeys.Send(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send)